# Retrieve data from url with axios (scraping)

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, axios

I try to retrieve data (scraping) from a url with Get method (axios) but it doesn't retrieve the data  what i looking for (piano) and no error is show. I use json to retrieve the data. Any idea what i'm doing wrong .dddddddddddddddddddddddddddd

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require ('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
const baseUrl = '**********/'; 

const axiosCookieJarSupport = require('axios-cookiejar-support').default;
const tough = require('tough-cookie');
 
axiosCookieJarSupport(axios);
 
const cookieJar = new tough.CookieJar();
function scrapeUrl(url, items=[]) {
 
  const params = {
  keywords: "piano",
  latitude:40.489353,
  longitude:-3.6827461,
  };

    return axios
      .get(baseUrl + "search", {
              params,
              jar: cookieJar,
              withCredentials: true,
            })
        .then(response => {
            const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
     const pageItems = $('.container-wall .card-product-content').toArray()
     tracked').toArray()
            .map(item => {
                const $item = $(item);
             // console.log('todo', $item);
                return {
                  //  id: $item.attr('data-adid'),
                   title: $item.find('.card-product-image').attr('alt'),
                   link: baseUrl + $item.parent('a').attr('href'),
                   image:  $item.find('.card-product-image').attr('src'),
                   price: $item.find('.product-info-price').text(),
              
                };
            });
        const allItems = items.concat(pageItems);
        console.log(pageItems.length,'items retrieved', allItems.length, 
        'acumulated');
        const nextUrl = $('.pagination .next a').attr('href');

        return nextUrl ? scrapeUrl(baseUrl + nextUrl, allItems) : allItems;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error', error);
        return items;
    });
```

}

```
scrapeUrl(baseUrl + initialUrl)
.then(items => {
    process.stdout.write(JSON.stringify(items));

    fs.writeFile('./items.json', JSON.stringify(items), 'utf8', function(error) {
        if (error) return console.log('error', error);
        console.log(items.length, 'items saved');
    }); 
});
```

Comment: There's a copy-paste issue in the code; I can also see two other problems: a) you are never actually calling the `scrapeUrl` function, at least not in the code in the question b) that page loads the search results via ajax, which means scraping the page won't work without using a headless browser that runs their JS code first

Comment: i put the calling

Answer (score 0):

i switch to puppeteer and headless Chrome as Chris sayed it's better than axios/cheerio becouse nowadays when many of the websites are built as a single page application and gets rendered dynamically on the client it might not be possible to get the content.